# How to send chat notificattion to user offline/online by socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I can send messages to others by socket when they are in a room but now I want to send a message when other users are not in a specific room or offline, as a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intergrate database with the socket application then only you store message offline and display to user when online.

Comment: I have already integrated database and can display messages when user online but I want to show these messages as a notification when a user other room or come offline to online